# Unable to change folder location for uploaded files

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, phpmyadmin, image-uploading

I would like to change my $target directory, currently in php/images/ to uploads/images/, but for some reason it won't work for some reason and no images upload to that folder but is restricted only to php/images and I don't know whats causing this.

All images I upload get uploaded to phpmyadmin and load into my images.php page so all that is working just something about the $target is not working.

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "media");

$msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

  $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

  $target = "php/images/".basename($image);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image_name) "
          . "VALUES ('$image')";

  mysqli_query($db, $sql);

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
      $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
  }else{
      $msg = "Failed to upload image";
  }
}
?>

<form id='imageForm' method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
   <div>
       <input class="file-upload" type="file" name='image' accept='image/*' />
   </div>
   <div class="upload-button">
       <button class="" name='upload'>UPLOAD</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**images.php**

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "media");
$uploaded = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($uploaded)) {
  echo "<ul class='img_container'>";
      echo "<li><img class='img_box' src='php/images/".$row['image_name']."' ></li>";
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: have you check the access permissions of the uploads/images folder? Your web server might not be allowed to write in this folder.

Comment: Wow. I feel stupid right now lol. Yea that solved my problem. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting blob in mysql database, you can use blobs(base64) but if you load to much images it slows your website, se here you have it

```
   if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    if($_FILES['image']['error'] > 0) { echo 'Error during upload, try again'; }

        //We won't use $_FILES['file']['type'] to check the file extension for security purpose

        //Set up valid image extensions
        $extsAllowed = array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png' );

        //Extract extention from uploaded file
            //substr return ".jpg"
            //Strrchr return "jpg"

        $extUpload = strtolower( substr( strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'], '.') ,1) ) ;
        //Check if the uploaded file extension is allowed

        if (in_array($extUpload, $extsAllowed) ) { 

        //Upload the file on the server

      $name = "{$_FILES['image']['name']}";
      $imgName = rand(5, 99999);
      $image = 'php/images/'.$imgName.'.jpg';
      $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $image);

      }
        if(result){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image_name) "
              . "VALUES ('$image')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
        }else{
         $msg = "Failed to upload image";
        }
    }
```

also check if you have permission to write on that directory.